# VNDK namespaces are missing in linker configuration file(ld.config.txt) in Android

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-source, dynamic-linking, bsp

I am working with Android-13. I enabled VNDK by `BOARD_VNDK_VERSION := current` . When i checked the linker configuration file(**ld.config.txt**) in /linkerconfig/ld.config.txt i didn't find the vndk namespaces(like `namespace.vndk.search.paths = /system/apex/com.android.vndk.33/` ). What i have to do for getting the VNDK namespaces in the linker configuration file. With this my error

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service": library "libminijail.so" not found: needed by /vendor/lib/libavservices_minijail.so in namespace (default)
```

will be resolved. what i am expecting was, my linker configuration file should contain something specific to VNDK like :

```
....
namespace.vndk.isolated = true
namespace.vndk.search.paths = /system/apex/com.android.vndk.33/
namespace.vndk.permitted.paths = /system/apex/com.android.vndk.33/
namespace.vndk.links = default
....
```

I tried enabling the VNDK through BOARD_VNDK_VERSION := current